# Add input on click ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I have a problem, when I click on a button to add a new line of multiple input, the data is noted in all the inputs! can you help me please I have been on this problem for several days and I cannot solve it, thanks

```
    {inputs.map((inputValue, index) => <>
     <Number key={"addQ" + index}
             type="input"
             placeholder="3"
             name="quantiteTab[]"
             label="Quantité*"
             classField="col-lg-2"
             onChange={(value) => setInputs(inputs => {
                 let copy = [...inputs];
                 copy[index] = value.target.value;
                 return copy;
            })}
            value={inputValue}/>
            <Number key={"addP" + index}
                    type="input"
                    placeholder="206"
                    name="poidsTab[]"
                    label="Poids total (kg)"
                    classField="col-lg-3"
                    onChange={(value) => setInputs(inputs => {
                      let copy = [...inputs];
                      copy[index] = value.target.value;
                          return copy;
                   })}
           value={inputValue}/>
   <button className="button add-line" type="button" onClick={() => setInputs(inp => [...inp,''])}>Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Number key={"addQ" + index}` - the key should not be dependent on an array  index. Randomly generate a key or pass something constant but unique from `inputValue`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, do you have an idea for my problem ? I stuck since a long time ahah, help isn't refused ! ;)